# Emails Not Sending for Uncompleted Orders within Selected Time Slot

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am encountering an issue with my system where I am attempting to send emails to my delivery drivers if an order is not completed within the time slot chosen by the customer. Despite successfully adding the order meta, the emails are not being sent, and I am struggling to identify the root cause of this problem. I am seeking the expertise of the community to help me understand and resolve this issue. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Add custom column to admin orders page
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'gojo_add_custom_order_columns');
function gojo_add_custom_order_columns($columns) {
    // Check if the current user has either 'Shop manager' or 'Administrator' role
    if (current_user_can('shop_manager') || current_user_can('administrator')) {
        $columns['gojo_order_delayed'] = 'Order Delayed';
    }
    return $columns;
}

// Populate the custom column with data
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'gojo_custom_order_column_content', 10, 2);
function gojo_custom_order_column_content($column, $post_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($post_id);

    if ($column === 'gojo_order_delayed' && in_array($order->get_status(), array('processing', 'driver-assigned', 'out-for-delivery'))) {
        $delivery_date = get_post_meta($post_id, 'Delivery Date', true);
        $time_slot = get_post_meta($post_id, 'Time Slot', true);

        if ($delivery_date && date('j F, Y') === $delivery_date && $time_slot) {
            $current_time = current_time('H:i'); // Get current time in 24-hour format

            list($start_time, $end_time) = explode(' - ', $time_slot);

            $order_id = $order->get_id(); // Get order ID

            if (strtotime($current_time) > strtotime($end_time)) {
                // If order is delayed, add meta data
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'Order Delayed', 'Yes');
                echo '<span style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">Order Delayed. Please call the driver.</span>';

                // Check for email conditions and send email only if 'Order Delayed' is 'Yes'
                $status = $order->get_status();
                if ($status == 'driver-assigned' || $status == 'out-for-delivery') {
                    $meta_data = $order->get_items();

                    foreach ($meta_data as $meta) {
                        if ($meta->key === 'lddfw_driverid') {
                            $driver_id = $meta->value;
                        }
                        if ($meta->key === 'Order Delayed') {
                            $order_delay_value = $meta->value;

                            if ($order_delay_value === 'Yes') {
                                // Check if 'Order Delayed' is 'Yes' before sending the email
                                $order_delayed = get_post_meta($post_id, 'Order Delayed', true);
                                if ($order_delayed === 'Yes') {
                                    // Check if email has already been sent
                                    $email_sent_order_delayed = $order->get_meta('email_sent_order_delayed', true);

                                    if ($email_sent_order_delayed != 'Yes') {
                                        // Get driver information
                                        $driver = get_userdata($driver_id);
                                        $driver_name = $driver->display_name;
                                        $driver_email = $driver->user_email;

                                        // Send email to driver
                                        $subject = 'Order no. ' . $order_id . ' is Delayed'; // Use $order_id
                                        $message = 'Hello ' . $driver_name . ',<br><br> Order no. ' . $order_id . ' has been delayed. Please call the customer & assure order will be delivered soon!.<br>';

                                        // Get customer information
                                        $billing_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();
                                        $shipping_phone = $order->get_shipping_phone();

                                        // Add phone numbers to the message
                                        $message .= 'Billing Phone: ' . $billing_phone . '<br>';
                                        $message .= 'Shipping Phone: ' . $shipping_phone . '<br>';

                                        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

                                        add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'gojo_original_mail_address_email');
                                        add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'gojo_email_name_order_delayed');

                                        if (wp_mail($driver_email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                            // Update email_sent meta value
                                            $order->update_meta_data('email_sent_order_delayed', 'Yes');
                                            $order->save();
                                            remove_filter('wp_mail_from', 'gojo_original_mail_address_email');
                                            remove_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'gojo_email_name_order_delayed');
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}

function gojo_original_mail_address_email() {
    $email = 'ovenfreshretail01@gmail.com';
    return $email;
}

function gojo_email_name_order_delayed() {
    return 'Oven Fresh';
}
```

Here is a brief explanation of the code:

**1. Adding Custom Column (gojo_add_custom_order_columns):**

```
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'gojo_add_custom_order_columns');

function gojo_add_custom_order_columns($columns) {
    if (current_user_can('shop_manager') || current_user_can('administrator')) {
        $columns['gojo_order_delayed'] = 'Order Delayed';
    }
    return $columns;
}
```

This part uses the WordPress filter manage_edit-shop_order_columns to add a custom column to the WooCommerce admin orders page. The column is named 'Order Delayed,' and it will be visible only to users with the 'Shop manager' or 'Administrator' roles.

**2. Populating Custom Column (gojo_custom_order_column_content):**

```
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'gojo_custom_order_column_content', 10, 2);

function gojo_custom_order_column_content($column, $post_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($post_id);

    // Check if the column is 'gojo_order_delayed' and the order is in a specific state
    if ($column === 'gojo_order_delayed' && in_array($order->get_status(), array('processing', 'driver-assigned', 'out-for-delivery'))) {
        
        // Retrieve delivery date and time slot from post meta
        $delivery_date = get_post_meta($post_id, 'Delivery Date', true);
        $time_slot = get_post_meta($post_id, 'Time Slot', true);

        // Check conditions for order delay
        if ($delivery_date && date('j F, Y') === $delivery_date && $time_slot) {
            $current_time = current_time('H:i'); // Get current time in 24-hour format

            list($start_time, $end_time) = explode(' - ', $time_slot);

            // If current time is later than the end time, mark the order as delayed
            if (strtotime($current_time) > strtotime($end_time)) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'Order Delayed', 'Yes');
                echo '<span style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">Order Delayed. Please call the driver.</span>';

                // Check for email conditions and send email only if 'Order Delayed' is 'Yes'
                $status = $order->get_status();
                $order_delay_value = get_post_meta($post_id, 'Order Delayed', true);

                if (($status == 'driver-assigned' || $status == 'out-for-delivery') && $order_delay_value === 'Yes') {
                    // Further checks and email sending handled in the next functions
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function populates the custom column with content. It checks if the column is 'gojo_order_delayed' and if the order is in one of the specified states ('processing', 'driver-assigned', 'out-for-delivery'). If these conditions are met, it checks additional conditions related to delivery date and time. If the order is delayed, it updates the post meta with 'Order Delayed' set to 'Yes' and displays a message in the custom column.

**3. Sending Delayed Order Email (send_delayed_order_email):**

```
// Check for email conditions and send email only if 'Order Delayed' is 'Yes'
                $status = $order->get_status();
                if ($status == 'driver-assigned' || $status == 'out-for-delivery') {
                    $meta_data = $order->get_items();

                    foreach ($meta_data as $meta) {
                        if ($meta->key === 'lddfw_driverid') {
                            $driver_id = $meta->value;
                        }
                        if ($meta->key === 'Order Delayed') {
                            $order_delay_value = $meta->value;

                            if ($order_delay_value === 'Yes') {
                                // Check if 'Order Delayed' is 'Yes' before sending the email
                                $order_delayed = get_post_meta($post_id, 'Order Delayed', true);
                                if ($order_delayed === 'Yes') {
                                    // Check if email has already been sent
                                    $email_sent_order_delayed = $order->get_meta('email_sent_order_delayed', true);

                                    if ($email_sent_order_delayed != 'Yes') {
                                        // Get driver information
                                        $driver = get_userdata($driver_id);
                                        $driver_name = $driver->display_name;
                                        $driver_email = $driver->user_email;

                                        // Send email to driver
                                        $subject = 'Order no. ' . $order_id . ' is Delayed'; // Use $order_id
                                        $message = 'Hello ' . $driver_name . ',<br><br> Order no. ' . $order_id . ' has been delayed. Please call the customer & assure order will be delivered soon!.<br>';

                                        // Get customer information
                                        $billing_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();
                                        $shipping_phone = $order->get_shipping_phone();

                                        // Add phone numbers to the message
                                        $message .= 'Billing Phone: ' . $billing_phone . '<br>';
                                        $message .= 'Shipping Phone: ' . $shipping_phone . '<br>';

                                        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

                                        add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'gojo_original_mail_address_email');
                                        add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'gojo_email_name_order_delayed');

                                        if (wp_mail($driver_email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                            // Update email_sent meta value
                                            $order->update_meta_data('email_sent_order_delayed', 'Yes');
                                            $order->save();
                                            remove_filter('wp_mail_from', 'gojo_original_mail_address_email');
                                            remove_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'gojo_email_name_order_delayed');
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

This function constructs and sends an email to the driver if certain conditions are met. It uses the wp_mail function to send an HTML email to the driver with information about the delayed order. It also includes customer phone numbers in the email content.

```
function gojo_original_mail_address_email() {
    $email = 'ovenfreshretail01@gmail.com';
    return $email;
}

function gojo_email_name_order_delayed() {
    return 'Oven Fresh';
}
```

These functions are filters that set the sender email address and name for the email. They are used during the email sending process and are added and removed using the add_filter and remove_filter functions.

This code, when executed, enhances the WooCommerce admin orders page by providing information about delayed orders in a custom column and sending notification emails to drivers associated to those orders for delayed orders.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail

Comment: where is your wp_mail function executed ? Its missing here.

Comment: hey @Snuffy I've updated my question further explaining everything, In the provided code snippet, the wp_mail function is executed within the nested conditional block. Here is the relevant portion where wp_mail is used: ```if (wp_mail($driver_email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    // Update email_sent meta value
    $order->update_meta_data('email_sent_order_delayed', 'Yes');
    $order->save();
    remove_filter('wp_mail_from', 'gojo_original_mail_address_email');
    remove_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'gojo_email_name_order_delayed');
}
```

Comment: @Snuffy  This code checks if the wp_mail function returns true, indicating that the email was sent successfully. If the email is sent successfully, it proceeds to update the email_sent_order_delayed meta value for the order, saves the order, and then removes the filters applied to the sender email and name.

In summary, the wp_mail function is executed within the conditional block, and the subsequent code handles the actions to be taken after the email has been sent.